# D3 legend not appearing due to legendColor

Tags: javascript, d3.js

My legend won't appear for my heatmap. It says the error: "d3.legendColor is not a function" but I am unsure of how to change it to work.

full chart and full code: http://codepen.io/jeffm64/pen/gwQAyb

The code

```
var colorScale = d3.scaleQuantile()
                       .domain([minVariance + baseTemp, maxVariance + baseTemp])
                       .range(colors);

//creates the legend for the heatmap
    d3.select("svg")
      .append("g")
      .attr("class", "legendQuant")
      .attr("transform", "translate(20,20)");

    var legend = d3.legendColor()
      .labelFormat(d3.format(".2f"))
      .useClass(true)
      .scale(colorScale);

    svg.select(".legendQuant")
      .call(legend);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Susie Lu's *d3 Legend* (http://d3-legend.susielu.com/), you'll have to reference it:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3-legend/2.13.0/d3-legend.js"></script>
```